# Redis TLS with spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, ssl

Is it necessary to add the .p12 certificate to my Java truststore when establishing a TLS connection using a Spring Boot application with a Redis server that also has TLS enabled?

Adding a certificate manually on production can create a dependency,
I want to avoid adding the .p12 certificate to the truststore.

When I don't add the truststore.p12 file, which contains ca.pem, my Spring Boot application gives me an error stating that "trustAnchors must not be empty.

I want to know above scenario is possible or not in my case and if I avoiding to adding truststore is it best practices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is default behavior when your make use of self signed certificate in server machine.

*"I want to avoid adding the .p12 certificate to the truststore."* this is exact same reason why server certificates are added to the truststore as a client.

Think about it ideally request to server should only and only come from legitimate clients (in your case spring app is client to redis server). adding certificate to truststore will make sure that only trusted clients are authorized to make the request.

So to answer your question adding certs to truststore is a common/well known practice done in web world.

Hope this helps. Thanks.

Comment: When we change our Redis certificate, we need to add it again to the truststore, my concern is I want avoid that process.

Comment: I do not see that as a challenge. anyways we do not change our servers frequently. but sure you can avoid that using something called as PKI setup. where target cert is signed by intermediate authority which is known/trusted to the client. you can have a look into it. and please consider accepting the answer if that helped.

Comment: How can I avoid using Public Key Infrastructure (PKI) in my case? I followed the redis documentation for connecting my Spring Boot code to a Redis server when TLS is enabled.https://redis.io/docs/clients/java/#:~:text=Connect%20to%20your%20production%20Redis%20with%20TLS&text=Before%20connecting%20your%20application%20to,are%20in%20the%20correct%20format.&text=Enter%20password%20to%20protect%20your,the%20keytool%20shipped%20with%20JDK.

Comment: Not recommended but to use redis with non-tls (non-secure/plain way.) This again is not recommend but doable if your redis service is not publicly exposed. (subnet with no internet access)

Comment: I followed the provided documentation to establish a connection. Is this a safe approach in a production environment? Please verify if you have knowledge about it        link       https://redis.io/docs/clients/java/#:~:text=Connect%20to%20your%20production%20Redis%20with%20TLS&text=Before%20connecting%20your%20application%20to,are%20in%20the%20correct%20format.&text=Enter%20password%20to%20protect%20your,the%20keytool%20shipped%20with%20JDK.